# Variadic templates and perfect forwarding to specific template class

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding, visual-c++-2013

I want to implement a perfect forwarding constructor in my "myArgs class",
which should only get involved for specializations of `myClassBase<>`.
Roughly speaking: call this constructor for each variation of `myClassBase<>`

But it won't compile: `'<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'myClass' to 'myArgs'.`

I think it's because the compiler can't deduce from `Args&&` to `myClassBase<T, D>`.

See this (very basic) example:

```
template <class T, class D>
class myClassBase
{
private:
    T data;
    D data2;
};

typedef myClassBase<char, int> myClass;

class myArgs
{
public:
    myClass m_data;

    template <class T, class D>
    myArgs(myClassBase<T, D>&& rhs) :
        m_data(std::forward< myClassBase<T, D> >(rhs))
    {
    }
};

template <class... Args>
void var_args(Args&&... args)
{
    myArgs( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}
```

Test the stuff:

```
myClass x;

var_args(x);
```

If i change the var_args function parameter from `void var_args(Args&&... args)` to `void var_args(Args... args)` it works.

Btw. in my real code myClass of course supports move semantics.

Thanks in advance.
Christian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <class T, class D>
myArgs(myClassBase<T, D>&& rhs) :
    m_data(std::forward< myClassBase<T, D> >(rhs))
{
}
```

`rhs` there is an rvalue reference, not a forwarding reference. A forwarding reference in a function parameter be of the form `T&&` where `T` is some deduced template parameter. You can fix this by having `T` deduced rather than specifying `myClassBase`.

```
template <class T>
myArgs(T&& rhs) :
    m_data(std::forward<T>(rhs))
{
}
```

If you want this function to only be valid if `T` is a `myClassBase`, you can write a trait to check it:

```
template <typename T>
struct isMyClassBaseImpl : std::false_type{};

template <typename T, typename D>
struct isMyClassBaseImpl<myClassBase<T,D>> : std::true_type{};

template <typename T>
using isMyClassBase = isMyClassBaseImpl<std::decay_t<T>>;
```

Then you can SFINAE it out:

```
template <class T, std::enable_if_t<isMyClassBase<T>::value>* = nullptr>
myArgs(T&& rhs) :
    m_data(std::forward<T>(rhs))
{
}
```